# Problem with initial render of a component

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing strange (to me at least) issue with a component where I fetch
data from the server upon initial render:

```
const [newestThree, setNewestThree] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    };
    console.log("CALLED1");
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/blog/posts/seo", headers)
      .then(resp => {
        console.log("CALLED2");
        setNewestThree([resp.data.message.slice(resp.data.message.length-3, resp.data.message.length]);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}, []);

const imageUrlForMobile1 = `http://localhost:5000/blog/fetch_card_image/${newestThree[0].slug}`; // throws "newestThree" undefined

return (
  ...
  ...
);
```

I've been trying to determine why sometimes `setNewestThree()` gets the value but mostly it doesn't and errors out. My understanding is that empty `[]` in `useEffect()` means that it will
be executed on initial render only and also on each refresh (F5). In my case it errors out.

I checked the server and appears that the request isn't even being sent most of the time.

Any ideas ?

Error output:

`TypeError: newestThree[0] is undefined`

Comment: Can you include an error in your post via updating it (edit)?

Comment: @Lith Error output added.

Comment: should be `[resp.data.message.slice(resp.data.message.length-3, resp.data.message.length)]`? You're missing a bracket after `resp.data.message.length`

Comment: @Harrison  No, sorry that's just a typo I made here. Brackets are fine in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageUrlForMobile1` constant declared when you did not get a response yet.
use a condition for declaring `imageUrlForMobile1`